# PyInstaller statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import kstest_normal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller, statsmodels

I'm using pyinstaller on one of my scripts but I'm getting an error on the line of code I wrote:

```
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import kstest_normal
```

The command I used was

```
pyinstaller fitness_of_statistical_tests.py --hidden-import=scipy.linalg.cython_blas --hidden-import=scipy.linalg.cython_lapack
```

The full error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: cannot import name 'lib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "D:\SEDS\gahndiwashingtonmethod\fitness_of_statistical_tests_view.py", line 11, in <module>
    from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import kstest_normal
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py", line 11, in <module>
    from statsmodels.datasets import webuse
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\datasets\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import (anes96, cancer, committee, ccard, copper, cpunish, elnino,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\datasets\anes96\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .data import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\datasets\anes96\data.py", line 90, in <module>
    from statsmodels.datasets import utils as du
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\datasets\utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame, Index
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 311, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: 'lib' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
fitness_of_statistical_tests returned -1
```

All of these imports work in the python interpreter, but it's just when I run the exe from PyInstaller that all this stuff breaks.

Comment: What happens if you `--hidden-import=pandas`?

Comment: Same problem, I also tried --hidden-import=statsmodels